# Flight from Morocco to London has a 4S-4 connection in Madrid, do I need to enter Schengen?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, mad

Extracting the core question from [Panicking: Used all my Schengen days and need to transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137884/4188).

I looked at https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/connections-between-terminals.htm and the people mover needs a boarding pass which makes me wonder whether it's air side.

Answer (score 1):

This [video of how to transfer between Terminal 4 and Terminal 4S](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUh8ofG3Dqg) seems to indicate that yes, you would clear passport control before boarding the train (see 2:02 in the video).

Comment: It seems that 4S is for non-Schengen flights, while 4 is mostly, but not exclusively, for Schengen flights.  There's a small area of 4 for non-Schengen flights.  It is conceivable that there are special arrangements for those who are unauthorized to enter the Schengen area to make the transfer without using the train.

Comment: The airport website mentions an [airside transit bus](https://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/transportation/connections-between-terminals.htm) leaving terminal 4S but strangely it doesn't say that it stops at terminal 4. This seems like a bizarre omission when it will be mostly Iberia passengers affected.

Comment: I already asked Iberia on [twitter](https://twitter.com/chx/status/1124678782105710592) but received no answer (yet). I might DM them later.